# Sycn audio and video in html5 javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video

I have two files one is video file with no volume and the other one is audio. So I'm running these two files in `<audio>` and `<video>` tags. I want that when both file are ready to play then the video play otherwise wait until both are not able to play. So, what I used for this.
`canPlay` is not working well for me because it can check only one of them at a time.
Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
  audio.addEventListener('canplay',function(){
    audio.play();
    video.play(); 
  });

  video.addEventListener('canplay',function(){
    audio.play();
    video.play(); 
  });
```

I try this but this is not working because whenever one of them is running it play both without care about other one, Because there is `play()` for both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen for [`canplaythrough`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/canplaythrough) event of both the elements and if both `can`, trigger `.play()` on both the elements.

> *The canplaythrough event is fired when the user agent can play the media, and estimates that enough data has been loaded to play the media up to its end without having to stop for further buffering of content.*

Try this:

```js
var audioCan = false,
  videoCan = false;
audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
  audioCan = true;
  playAll();
});

video.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
  videoCan = true;
  playAll();
});

function playAll() {
  if (audioCan && videoCan) {
    audio.play();
    video.play();
  }
}
```

**Edit:** You can achieve the same using promise.

Try this:

```js
var audioLoaded = new Promise(function(resolve) {
  audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
    resolve();
  });
});
var videoLoaded = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  video.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
    resolve();
  });
});

function playAll() {
  audio.play();
  video.play();
}
Promise.all([audioLoaded, videoLoaded]).then(playAll);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's working... I'm wondering how can I miss this simple logic.